navigate THREE.JS VRmode scene to A-frameVR mode scene
I'm currently looking for the solution to navigate the immersive scene from three.js to Aframe vr mode.
The current approch is  Existing vrMode in Three.js then enter VRmode in Aframe.
When I use this method to debug the Google Chrome webXR extension, it works perfectly. However, when I use it with the Oculus Quest 2 browser, the browser terminated itself before the aframe scene was render.
Is it recommended to switch scenes without exiting the Three.js VR mode?
